# Open a PDF file from a WinJS Application

Tags: pdf, windows-8, winjs

I've got an application in which the user clicks a button, and should be presented a PDF that is stored in the application.

They can view the PDF internally in the app, or launch the native windows PDF viewer, either way is fine.

How can I provide a link / event handler for the button click to launch a view of a PDF file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [LaunchFileAsync function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701465.aspx) of the Launcher class,

description: Starts the default app associated with the specified file, using the specified options.

example code:

```
Windows.System.Launcher.launchFileAsync(file, options).done( /* Your success and error handlers */ );
```

Comment: Following the example ends up with `success` being `false` in the callback. Code sample can be viewed here: http://pastie.org/4613116